# How to perform bitwise operations on a value stored in a table and use it in where clause of sql query?

Tags: sql, database, select, bit-manipulation, where-clause

This is the scenario. I have a column 'flag' in a table. This column stores a 32bit binary number in decimal form. For example 00000000000000000000000000000010 is stored as 2. I need to display all the records in the table in which the 26th bit of the value stored in 'flag' is set as '1'. How do I write sql query for this purpose?

Comment: What about other flags? Can they be set also?

Comment: Ya, they can be either be set or 0. I only want to display the records in the which the 26th bit of the value is set! Don't bother with the other bits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from tablename
where (flag & 64) = 64
```

The 26th bit corresponds to bit for 2 ^ 6 = 64. On SQL Server, & will do a bitwise-AND and return 64 only if the 64 bit is set in both operands.

Comment: I don't think this will work! If the stored value is 128, the record will be printed but the 26th bit will be 0!

Comment: Ooh yes, you are right. Let me modify that. Which DBMS BTW?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think its mysql. I was just asked to write an SQL query for the above said purpose!